# How to explicitly show that $\int_A\dfrac 12 (X(|\omega|) + X(-|\omega|)) d \mathbb{P} = \int_A X d \mathbb{P}$ over symmetric intervals

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, uniform-distribution

This is a follow-up to [my previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4544483/measure-theory-how-to-compute-a-conditional-expectation):

> Consider the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A},\mathbb{P})$, where $\Omega = (-1,1), \mathcal{A} = \mathcal{B((-1,1))}$ and $\mathbb{P}$ is the uniform distribution on $(-1,1)$. Let further $\mathcal{F} = \{A \in \mathcal{A} : A = -A \}$.  For an integrable RV $X$ show that $$\int_A\dfrac 12 (X(|\omega|) + X(-|\omega|)) d \mathbb{P} = \int_A X d \mathbb{P}$$ for all $A \in \mathcal{F}$.
>
> Remark: As usual $\mathcal{B}(\cdot)$ denotes the Borel Algebra.

I understand that the $A$ describe symmetric intervals around $0$. Using the linearity of the integral we may write

$$\int_A \dfrac 12 (X(|\omega|) + X(-|\omega|)) d \mathbb{P} = \dfrac 12 \int_A (X(|\omega|) d \mathbb{P}+ \dfrac 12 \int_A X(-|\omega|)) d \mathbb{P}$$

, but I fail to see how to now compute the summands explicitly. (I am not good in measure theory.) Could you please give me a hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\int_A X d\mathbb P = \frac12 \int_A X(t)\;dt,\qquad\text{(Lebesgue integral).}
$$
Let $B = A \cap (0,1)$.  Then, because $A$ is symmetric, we have
$$
A = B \cup (-B)\qquad\text{a disjoint union}
$$ except perhaps for the point $\{0\}$ which has measure zero.  So
$$
\frac12\int_A X(t)\;dt = \frac12\int_B X(t)\;dt + \frac12 \int_{-B}X(t)\;dt
$$
change variables $t=-s$ in the second one:
$$
\frac12\int_B X(t)\;dt + \frac12\int_B X(-s)\;ds
$$
and rename a dummy variable
$$
\frac12 \int_A X(t)\;dt =
\frac12\int_B X(t)\;dt + \frac12\int_B X(-t)\;dt
\tag1$$
This is probably the best way to write the answer.

But the OP has written it in a more complicated way.  How can we get that?

Similar to our derivation of $(1)$ [change variables in the first term, not the second], we may obtain
$$
\frac12 \int_A X(t)\;dt = \frac12 \int_{-B} X(-t)\;dt + \frac12 \int_{-B} X(t)\;dt
\tag2$$
Add $(1)$ and $(2)$
\begin{align}
\int_A X(t)\;dt &=
\frac12\int_B X(t)\;dt + \frac12\int_B X(-t)\;dt
 + \frac12 \int_{-B} X(-t)\;dt + \frac12 \int_{-B} X(t)\;dt
\\ & =
 \frac12\int_{B \cup (-B)} X(t)\;dt + \frac12\int_{B\cup(-B)} X(-t)\;dt
\\ & =
\int_A\frac12\big(X(t)+X(-t)\big)\;dt
\end{align}
the two values $t$, $-t$ are the same as the two values $|t|, -|t|$ in some order, so
$$
\int_A X(t)\;dt = \int_A\frac12\big(X(|t|)+X(-|t|)\big)\;dt
\\
\frac12\int_A X(t)\;dt = \frac12\int_A\frac12\big(X(|t|)+X(-|t|)\big)\;dt
$$
and finally
$$
\int_A X(\omega)\;d\mathbb P 
= \int_A \frac12\big(X(|\omega|)+X(-|\omega|)\big)\;d\mathbb P
\tag3$$
Why would you want to write $(1)$ in this more complicated form $(3)$?
Because now we can apply the definition of **conditional expectation** and conclude
$$
\mathbb E [ X \mid \mathcal F ](\omega) =
\frac12\big(X(|\omega|)+X(-|\omega|)\big)\qquad\text{a.s.}
\tag4$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detalied answer! I just have one more question: Why can we write $
\int_A X d\mathbb P = \frac12 \int_A X(t)\;dt,\qquad\text{(Lebesgue integral)}
$  ? As I said I am not good at measure theory; I understand that the $1/2$ comes from the assumed uniform distribution, but I fail to see why we can then write $dx$ instead of $d\lambda$. Is this some important theorem, or a consequence of one?

Comment: Using $dx$ for Lebesgue measure is just a matter of notation.  Here $X$ is assumed to be "integrable" so all of these Lebesgue integrals exist (even if the Riemann integrals may not).